# When will the block lift up the front wheel?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum, torque, statics

[image]
Here is my problem: the luggage is being pulled with force $T$ at an angle $\theta$. I'd like to know when the front wheel will lift up. How do I even start?

Before lifting it up, all I know is that with a force $T$ the luggage is going at a constant velocity. Therefore I used the conditions for equilibrium:
\begin{equation}
\sum_i{F_i} \,\,\,\,\text{and}\,\,\,\,\sum_i{r_i\times F_i}
\end{equation}
However I want to find $T$ and $\theta$, as functions of $\mu$ friction coefficient, $g$ gravitational acceleration and for which the front wheel will lift up.

I'm using $F_i = -\mu |R_i|\vec{i}$

Thanks

How can I find it?

Comment: If the luggage lifts up due to the force T, then the pivot point is the rear wheels of the luggage, so you have to calculate the torque about that point. The weight of the luggage will give a clockwise-acting torque about this point. As for the force T, it seems that there is some info missing here. The magnitude and orientation of the torque due to T depends on where the strap is attached to the luggage and not just the θ angle.

Comment: To be honest I've drawn it very badly, the force $T$ is applied on the top right angle of the luggage! Also, how do you calculate/understand whether the torque js clockwise or anticlockwise? I know it's the cross product, but that only gives me a perpendicular vector

Comment: It is a bad practice to edit a question  _after_ it has answers if the final edit is a completely different question. I un-edited the question in order to match the answers.

If you have a new question, please post a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is a *homework & exercises* type question, I'll only point you in the right direction.

First add some dimensions and a coordinate system:

[image: Luggage being pulled]

> Before lifting it up, all I know is that with a force $T$ the luggage is going at a constant velocity

By Newton this means that there's no net force and no net torque acting on the suitcase:

$$\Sigma_i \vec{F}_i=0$$
$$\Sigma \vec{\tau}_i=0$$

First look at all forces in the $y$-direction:

$T\sin\theta+R_1+R_2-W=0\tag{1}$

The forces in the $x$-direction:

$T\cos\theta-\mu R_1-\mu R_2=0\tag{2}$

Finally a torque balance. We can make this balance about *any point*, so it's desirable to choose the point carefully. We choose the point where $\vec{T}$ acts on the luggage because that way the torque exerted by $\vec{T}$ and $\vec{R_2}$ is $0$. The balance then becomes:

$R_1\times L-W\times \frac{L}{2}=0\tag{3}$

You now have three equations and three unknowns. Solve the system of equations for these unknowns. This will give you an expression of $T$ inthe *knowns only*:

$$T=f(\mu,W)$$

Increasing $T$ above that value will cause net torque and thus *lift*.

Comment: Okay thank you @Gert. I'm gonna try to work it out. However what kind of software did you use to add the coordinates? And finally, what would happen if I took the torque about other points? Say where $R_2$ or $R_1$ act? Would I still get the same?

Comment: Oh never mind you said we can choose it by any point, so I guess your choice just gives easier calculations, thanks!

Comment: And also, you say 3 unknowns, but I see T, $\theta$, $R_1$ and $R_2$ which are 4

Comment: $\theta$ has to be a known. Either $\theta$ or the magnitude of $T$, otherwise the problem isn't solvable: it has *only three degrees of freedom*.